# Изменить содержимое делегата только в одной ячейке

Tags: c++, qt, gui

Есть делегат для отображения QComboBox, он наследуется от `QStyledItemDelegate`. Переопределены методы `setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index)`, `setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,const QModelIndex &index) const`, `createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option , const QModelIndex & index ) const`. Также определена собственная модель на основе `QAbstractTableModel`

Предположим, во view я получаю сигнал `dataChanged` от модели, как мне дальше получить делегата именно для нужной ячейки?
Как можно заменить содержимое списка второго комбобокса только в одной ячейке? У делегата-комбобокса есть метод установки списка. `itemDelegateForColumn` не подойдет, т.к. изменится список у всей колонки, а нужно только в текущей строке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно для модели объявить пользовательскую роль, например `MY_COMBO_ROLE`. Данные с этой ролью нужно запрашивать из модели в функии делегата `setEditorData` и потом действовать по ситуации, от задачи зависит.

Например, у вас два захардкоженых списка для комбобокса. Один список используется всегда, а второй в особом случае. Об этом особом случае сообщает модель с помощью роли `MY_COMBO_ROLE`. Поэтому при каждом `setEditorData` вы сначала выполняете что-то типа `model->data(index, MY_COMBO_ROLE)`, потом анализируете полученные данные и выбираете с каким списком создавать комбобокс. И далее как обычно.

Второй вариант. В ответ на запрос данных с ролью `MY_COMBO_ROLE` модель возвращает сразу готовый список для комбобокса. То есть решение о том какой список показывать принимает модель, а не делегат. Что более логично.

[Подробнее про роли](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)